# If a Queue had a linked list, but the linked list only had a reference to head, what would be the running time of enqueue and dequeue?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, queue

If a Queue were implemented with a Linked List, but the linked list only had a
reference to head, what would be the running time of enqueue and what would be the
running time of dequeue?

Comment: What do you think? Share your thought process, and where you are stuck or doubting.

Comment: I am not sure where to start

Comment: At the `head` ? We appreciate questions that show effort, traces of research, attempts.

Comment: I know that I have to think about FIFO. No matter how many nodes you add, the head position stays the same. So I'm thinking that the run time for both would be N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with a quote from [Wikipedia's article on Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)#Queue_implementation):

> There are several efficient implementations of FIFO queues. An efficient implementation is one that can perform the operations—en-queuing and de-queuing—in O(1) time.
>
> - Linked list
>
>   - [...]
>   - A regular singly linked list only has efficient insertion and deletion ***at one end***. [...]

This really is the essence. As enqueue and dequeue operations affect the list at opposite ends of the list, and we only have a reference of one of those two ends, we will have to "walk" to the other end to be able to do the other operation there.

We can choose which end of the linked list will serve as the end where items are enqueued (added), while the other end will be where items are dequeued (extracted). The `head` of the linked list can be either -- it is a design choice.

Let's assume that *enqueue* will add an entry *at the end* of the linked list (after the current tail of the list), and *dequeue* will return the head-entry, and remove that node from the list. Then the code would be like this -- I use Python as example:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def enqueue(self, value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
        else:
            node = self.head
            while node.next is not None:
                node = node.next
            node.next = Node(value)
    
    def dequeue(self):
        if self.head is None:
            raise ValueError("Queue is empty")
        else:
            value = self.head.value
            self.head = self.head.next
            return value
```

So for `enqueue`, we need to step through the list, starting from the `head` node, finding where is the tail of the list. Then we create a node for the given value and link it after that tail node, making the list one entry longer. As we need to traverse the whole list before we can perform the addition, this has a time complexity of O(n).

For `dequeue`, we immediately have the node where the value is that we need to get: it is the `head` node. So there is no need to traverse the list here. We only must change the `head` reference, so that it refers to the next node in the list, dropping the first node from it. This operation has a time complexity of O(1).

Now, we could also take the alternative design decision where the linked list will grow in the other direction, and `enqueue` will add a new node before the current `head` node. The `dequeue` method would then have to get the value in the tail node and remove that tail node from the list. As you can see, now the `enqueue` operation has a time complexity of O(1), while the `dequeue` has a time complexity of O(n).

So either way, there will be one of the two that has a time complexity of O(n), while the other has a time complexity of O(1).

Comment: and what if  a Stack were implemented with a Linked List, but the linked list only had a reference to head, what would be the running time of pop and push?

Comment: What do you think? You can use the reasoning presented in this answer. Start by identifying the difference between queue and stack and how that influences the reasoning.

Comment: Will pop be O(n) and push be O(1)?

Comment: Why do you think so? Please explain what steps you take to arrive at that conclusion.

Comment: As to the stack. Ask yourself this: how many ends of the stack (front, back) are involved in the pop and push operations?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to build a queue backed by a linked list that only stores a pointer to the head of the list, but where both enqueue and dequeue take time O(1). The idea is to use a doubly-linked list linked in a cycle, such that the first element of the list points backwards to the last element and the last element of the list points forwards to the first element. For example:

```
head
 |    +---+     +---+     +---+     +---+
 +--> | 1 | <-> | 2 | <-> | 3 | <-> | 4 |
      +---+     +---+     +---+     +---+
        ^                             ^
        |                             |
        +-----------------------------+
```

To perform a dequeue in time O(1), we simply remove and return the first linked list cell. As we do, we rewire the cells just before and just after it to point to one another, like this:

```
head -------------+
                  |
                  v
                +---+     +---+     +---+
                | 2 | <-> | 3 | <-> | 4 |
                +---+     +---+     +---+
                  ^                   ^
                  |                   |
                  +-------------------+
```

To perform an enqueue in time O(1), insert a new value positioned between the first element and the last element, like this:

```
head -------------+
                  |
                  v
                +---+     +---+     +---+
                | 2 | <-> | 3 | <-> | 4 |
                +---+     +---+     +---+
                  ^                   ^
                  |       +---+       |
                  +-----> | 5 | <-----+   
                          +---+
```

I'll leave the actual pointer juggling details to you to sort out, but they're pretty straightforward, arguably easier than what a regular linked list queue would look like because there are fewer boundary conditions to check.